# How do I quickly insert many new rows into a table in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have a table which has 9 rows.  It needs to have 59 rows.

I know the trick where you highlight say 3 rows then do insert and it gives you three new rows.  That approach obviously does not work as well if the number of rows to be added is far greater than the number already present.

Is there any better way to add the 50 rows quickly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1**

Go to the **last cell** of the **last row**. Then every time you press <kbd>tab</kbd> it will insert a new row ... keep <kbd>tab</kbd> pressed to quickly insert many rows.

**Method 2**

From [Insert multiple lines in a table](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/add-x-number-of-rows-to-a-table/fc1c4c4e-2388-4bbb-9708-e98bceaa26bc) :

You can do it with a macro easy enough:

```
Sub ScratchMacro()
'A basic Word macro coded by Greg Maxey
Dim lngIndex As Long, lngRowsToAdd As Long, lngPosit As Long
Dim oTbl As Word.Table
  If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    lngRowsToAdd = InputBox("How many rows?", "Add Rows", 1)
    Set oTbl = Selection.Tables(1)
    lngPosit = Selection.Rows(1).Range.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber)
    For lngIndex = 1 To lngRowsToAdd
      oTbl.Rows.Add (oTbl.Rows(lngPosit))
    Next lngIndex
  End If
End Sub
```

See: http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/installing_employing_macros.html for instructions to employ the VBA code provided above.

Comment: Yeah I see what you are saying for Method 1.  If you _hold down_ the tab key, that will pretty quickly generate new rows for you.  It is just a matter of counting them correctly.  Scripting is also an option I suppose as in Method 2.  I think I would choose Method 1 between the 2 of them because it is fast enough and this is really a one-time occurrence.  I don't find myself editing many word documents.

Answer (score 0):

- Highlight a row (or more), and hit insert (as you know).
- Then hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to repeat (aka: [Redo](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-word-HP010370109.aspx#BM3)) that last insert, and let go when you have enough rows added.

Comment: `F4` could be a good alternative to `Ctrl`+`Y`.